# Programatically load database setup & compare with expected database in DBUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dbunit, spring-test

I annotate my test methods like this:

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup("/default_database_data.xml")
@ExpectedDatabase(value = "/expected_database_1.xml", assertionMode = NON_STRICT)
```

is it possible to manually perform the things that `@DatabaseSetup` and `@ExpectedDatabase` does:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  // DBUnit.setup("/default_database_data.xml");
  dao.insert(...);
  // DBUnit.expected("/expected_database_1.xml");
}
```

I made the syntax up, just to give you an idea of what I need: perform 2 setups and assertions in one unit test.

Comment: why would you want to do two setups? Can you plz explain?

Comment: DBUnit doesn't clean auto-generated IDs (sequences). In my *expected sets* I have tables with those IDs (and foreign keys pointing to those IDs). If the sequeces are not cleared, then the order of tests dictates the IDs of rows. **So either** I order the tests or clear the sequences or test foreign keys somehow different.. I don't know about any such solution, so I planned to have 1 test which calls non-test methods containing actual .. test code. Between the calls I need to reset & load DB.

Comment: two things that might work, check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813684/how-to-revert-the-database-back-to-the-initial-state-using-dbunit. And also this annotation: @DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) on the class.

Comment: `@DitirtiesContext` seems to make my tests run in order.. could this be true?

Comment: not really. I just clears the application context. Read the documentation on it.

Comment: I did, tests do pass but I didn't change the expected sets (they have IDs that match the order of tests)

Comment: that could easy be a side-affect actually. But I'm glad the tests pass :) Nevertheless you should implement some cleaning method and run it after each test method. Ill post this as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

two things that might work, check this link.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813684/how-to-revert-the-database-back-to-the-initial-state-using-dbunit)

And also this annotation:

```
  @DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

Comment: I just need to confirm if this actually works.. everywhere. And I'll accept :)

Comment: I can't confirm this, but generally seems to work. This **is not a good solution**, so, dear visitors, pay attention when using this :(