# How to set the value for table sequence in db unit?

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, dbunit

While running the DbUunit test cases I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (EMP_SYS.PK_EMP_ID) violated.
```

After analyzing  I understood that DatabaseOperation CLEAN_INSERT will just clean the data from the table but not reset the sequence.

Can anyone help me out to find any way to reset the SEQUENCE value through DB unit?

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: You can't do this unless you will need to add the PK ids to the dbunit.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

In your **dataset.xml** file you must specify tables in correctly insertion order, this means, the basic tables  first and then the related tables. This way `DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT` will delete tables in correctly delete order too (related tables first and then basic tables).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Cesar: Thank you for the response. 
I have defined the tables in a proper order. what i have noticed is while performing clean_insert it just clearing the data but not the table sequence number. i need a way to reset the sequence number.

Comment: Okey. Could you add your dataset file?

Comment: I found the answer in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607704/reset-sequence-in-dbunit