# spring-mvc-test auto rollback transactions configured with AOP xml on Service layer

Tags: spring-aop, spring-transactions, dbunit, spring-mvc-test, spring-test-dbunit

I have the following Spring MVC app stack:

*Controller -> Service -> DAO (Repository) -> Entity -> MySql InnoDB*

Transactions are configured to start from the Service layer using AOP xml config, and the app works perfectly:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(* *..service.*Service.*(..))" order="1"/>
</aop:config>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Now, I am writing Spring MVC tests using spring-mvc-test framework, UnitDB etc.
The test class has the following config:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        loader=WebContextLoader.class,
        locations={
            "classpath:spring/testContext.xml",
            "classpath:spring/testDispatcher-servlet.xml",
            "classpath:spring/security.xml"
        })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
            TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
            DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class})
@DatabaseSetup({"classpath:dbunit/initial-data.xml"})
```

The test looks something like this:

```
@Test
public void testSomeController() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/some/controller"));
}
```

Basically what I want is to test (use) the existing Spring AOP config inside the testing environment, initially setup some DB data, run the tests and **rollback everything after the tests are completed**.

In the above configuration, the tests are starting their own transaction which in the given propagation config is meeting another transaction at Service layer, started by AOP xml config and I get lock timeout error, because transaction started by test is waiting for the transaction started by AOP config at Service layer.

I am only writing tests and I shouldn't be modifying the actual code, only the test code. My task is **to find a way to rollback all changes made by tests with the given configuration**.

Any ideas appreciated.

EDIT

Here is the problematic case:

1. test class starts one big new transaction with auto-rollback for all tests.
2. dbunit fills the db with the initial data
3. test launches controller test
4. controller makes call to service layer e.g. save/update entity (inserted by DBUnit at the beginning of the test class), new transaction started here at service layer (configured by aop:config) but supported with the big transaction from the step #1
5. boom, error happens: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I think that the data inserted by DBUnit is still not committed because it is in the same transaction. I need to find a way to insert initial data with DBUnit in a separate transaction but still to roll it back at the end of the test.

Comment: Can you enable DEBUG logging and provide a complete log via [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: Yes I can, but I don't see a point for that. I am just asking for an abstract level explanation or idea, not a solution for some concrete bug.

Comment: It's not about some bug or something similar, it's just I don't know what's going on with your scenario from the details you provided and I'm thinking maybe some logs would shed some more light. If you don't see a point in sharing the logs, then don't do it and keep investigating the issue yourself.

Comment: Hey @AndreiStefan thanks for your interest in this issue. I just think you didn't understand the point, I am asking for some architectural proposal, on higher level, not a specific debugging issue.

Comment: Then I think what you have already should work. I don't see anything obvious that shouldn't rollback the changes.

Comment: Try removing the `DBUnit` for now and test with something else. Meaning insert the initial data in some other way, for example [Spring's embedded database support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-embedded-database-support). [Here's one example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/orm) with usage in a JUnit test from Spring's own test classes. After you remove DBUnit  and test with something else, if it works then you know it's DBUnit's fault.

Comment: I found various complaints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813684/how-to-revert-the-database-back-to-the-initial-state-using-dbunit) and [here](http://mikael-amborn.blogspot.ro/2011/02/dbunit-tests-with-spring-and-nested.html) about DBUnit, so it might be something wrong on how you use it or something that needs cleaning up after usage.

Answer (score 0):

I did 3 things that made it work:

1. Changed DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class to TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
2. Made my test class extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

   public class SomeControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
3. Change my data source from org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource to org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy as follows:

`<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
         <constructor-arg ref="dbcpDataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1+1"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    </bean>`

Hope it helps to someone